# Cómo realizar una consulta comparando 2 fechas en formato varchar en MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla llamada "Credito inmediato" con la columna "createdat" de tipo varchar que almacena fecha y hora en formato Europeo, (ejemplo= 04-11-2022 15:45:34): básicamente es un DateTime en formato Varchar. Necesito traerme los registros comprendidos entre fechas...

```sql
select 
    'Credito inmediato' as 'srvType', 
    reference, 
    createdat, 
    amount 
from transfer 
where createdat >= STR_TO_DATE('03-11-2022', '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s') 
    and createdat <= STR_TO_DATE('04-11-2022', '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s') 
    and (reference != 'null' and reference != '') 
ORDER BY 3 LIMIT 0;
```

Comment: Hay varias cosas que me... "intrigan" de tu query. Pero la principal: La fecha que ya está guardada en la BD es `Varchar`? Porque eso es un pésimo diseño de base de datos, justamente porque ahora no puedes hacer filtros entre rangos de fechas sin reinventar la rueda en el proceso. Podrías mostrarnos algunas filas con datos de esa tabla? Pueden ser solo las columnas que quieres en la query.

Comment: Ahora, eso es probablemente el menor de los problemas. La verdadera razón por la que tu query puede que no funcione, es por ese `ORDER BY`. Le estás pidiendo que ordene por la columna 3. O sea, por la columna llamada 3. No existe esa columna, asi que seguramente lanza un error 1504. Luego, tienes un `LIMIT 0`, que le dice a MySQL que regrese máximo 0 resultados.

Comment: @JettoMartínez corrigiendo tu segundo comentario: la columna no se llama "3", está ordenando por _la tercera columna en el select_, es decir, intenta hacer el orden por "createdat". Esto es un `ORDER BY` _por posición_, y [aparece en la documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html#id756773). Eso sí, de preferencia, es mejor no utilizarlo: ya fue _deprecado_ según dice la misma documentación.

Comment: Tienes razón, salté muy rápido a la conclusión de que estaba incorrecto. Jamás había visto usar el `ORDER BY`, y tiene sentido que haya sido deprecado. No soy super experto ni tengo 20 años de experiencia, pero he tocado los 4 motores principales SQL y jamás vi usar esa sintaxis. ¿Supongo que fue deprecada por falta de uso, más que por otra razón? TIL

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es convertir la columna `createdat` a fecha y compararla con una fecha de mysql, así:

```
SELECT 'Credito inmediato' as 'srvType', reference, createdat, amount 
FROM transfer 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(createdat,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') >= "2022-11-03 00:00:00"
AND STR_TO_DATE(createdat,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') <= "2022-11-02 00:00:00"
```

La fecha con la que vas a comparar debe estar en formato "Y-m-d H:i:s".

O si quieres usar el mismo formato de la columna, pues debes convertir también ese valor a formato de fecha de mysql así:

```
SELECT 'Credito inmediato' as 'srvType', reference, createdat, amount 
FROM transfer 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(createdat,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') >= STR_TO_DATE("02-11-2022 00:00:00",'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s')
AND STR_TO_DATE(createdat,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') <= STR_TO_DATE("04-11-2022 00:00:00",'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s')
```

Comment: Tienes un pequeño dedazo en los FROM.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Corregido ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por sus observaciones y sugerencias.
Amigo @Pipe tu query me ilumino y resolvió mi problema, muchas gracias!!

Comment: Con gusto. Considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada para asi ayudar a la comunidad. Saludos